# set an anchor tag's href to a value to make it unresponsive to javascript/jquery methods on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

so i have a jquery function that does something on the click of an anchor tag.now i want to make the button unresponsive to jquery on subsequent clicks. what should i do?
what i am doing is changing the innerHTML of the anchor tag on the first click and doing an AJAX call and during this time period i want nothing to happen when the user click on the same anchor tag again.

This is how i handle clicks through jquery

```
  $('.profileEdit label a').live('click', function () {
     // do something
  });
```

Comment: Use `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Instead of [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (it's deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9), you should use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood what you want you can just remove the 'onclick' attribute before the ajax call and set it up again at the end (success or fail).

@EDIT: final solution codes

```
function update(){
$("#bb").html('Updating');
$("body").off('click',"#bb");
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"profileUpdate.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{ 'value': '" + document.getElementById(string).value + "'" + ",'column':'" + string  + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                defaultSetter();                  
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                defaultSetter();
            }
        });

}

function defaultSetter(){
    $("#bb").html("Test");
    $("body").on('click','#bb', update);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    defaultSetter();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V3AAF/

## bb element is a button, not an anchor

Comment: i am not using the onclick attribute. I am handling the clicks through jQuery.

Comment: Jquery injects onclick attribute.

Comment: But you can use jquery .off() method to delete the onclick event instead of removeAttr().
I'll edit with an answer i found similar to my idea.

Comment: neither removing `href`or the `onclick` attributes worked. I was still able to click on the anchor tag which invoked the juqery function. To solve the problem i changed the text of the anchor(which i had to do anyways) and simply returned the function without doing anything if the text was changed and i changed back the text in my ajax function. Its surprising to know that the jQuery function didnt wait for the ajax function to complete even though the ajax function was called from within the jQuery function. so the jQuery function would finish first and the ajax afterwards.

Comment: also instead of `this.removeAttr('onclick');` it should be `$(this).removeAttr('onclick');` or it wont work

Comment: dont remove the attributes, remove the event. See my comment after: "But you can use jquery .off() method to delete the onclick event"
Also the jquery dont wait for the ajax result, that's way it is asynchronous. When ajax returns jquery function is called again at the success or error functions you had add to it.

Comment: add success/error to the calling juqery function??coz i already have a success and error function in my ajax call. And the ajax call is inside a javascript function  which is actually what the jQuery function calls so i figured jQuery would wait for the javascript function containing the ajax call to return.

Comment: Jquery dont wait for ajax request. When ajax returns with success or error events the function you assigned is runned. 
You can edit your answer and include that code or use jsfiddle so i can take a look but by your explanation that is good.
Only thing you need is to set .off() the click event and then in success AND error functions .on()

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/thunderbird/D6StN/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/thunderbird/D6StN/8/) its working without using the `.on() .off()` functions. just check the way i do it..if `.on() .off()` is more efficient i will switch over to using them.

Comment: your code was a little too much complex (many alerts and if else statements) for me too show you exactly what i wanted.
Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/V3AAF/
It is not working because that ajax url doesnt exist, but you can see the logic and apply on your app to test. Also i used buttons instead of anchor cause i think its more apropriated

Comment: nice logic Francisco. it works in jsfiddle but it wont even call the update function when i copy paste the exact same thing. when i change update to update(), the update function is called automatically and text is changed to updating and it stops there. The button is still clickable with the updating text and on clicking it the text changes to test and the same thing happens again. I am using asp.net 4.5.

Comment: i will edit your post with your new answer which works in jsfiddle and also include the way i did it and accept it.

Comment: why change update to update()?
update is assign, update() is a call.

Comment: i know but just update wont even call the update function on the button being clicked.i know it does in your jsfiddle.

Comment: alright i forgot to include the jquery1.7 script lol..it works correctly. I will edit your post and accept the answer.

Comment: xD lol, it happens. Also i used 1.8 i think, but it should work properly either way. Good to see you got it working. And thanks for editing.

Comment: my edit wasnt accepted i guess . You can edit your answer to include your jsfiddle code. Thx a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) if you only want the action to happen once on the first click?

```
$('.profileEdit label a').one('click', function () {
     alert('This will only alert on the first click');
});
```

If you happened a handler for further clicks on that element, just use return false, to prevent anything from happening after the first click:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    return false;
    alert('first time!');
});
```

[**jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rMG7b/6/)